# How can i display child terms under parent terms and assigned articles using entity field query?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, entities

Hi i have one content type with  two vocabulary term references one is called **category** and terms is **A,B,C** like the 2nd one **resources** it contains parent with child terms like below hierarchy

```
Resource 1 

    Subsection 1 
    Subsection 2
    Subsection 3
    Subsection 4

Resource 2
Resource 3
Resource 4
```

so i want to display articles based on first taxonomy  **category** then 2nd taxonomy **resources** related items using entity field query below hierarchy

```
Resource 1 

    Subsection 1 

        Article 1
        Article 2

    Subsection 2
    Subsection 3
    Subsection 4

Resource 2
Resource 3
Resource 4
```

below is my code for display only 1st taxonomy based articles fetching but i need to display both cases please help.

```
        <?php
        $vocab = taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load('resource_category');
        $trees = taxonomy_get_tree($vocab->vid);
        $array_tree = array();
        $array_tree1 = array();
        foreach($trees as $tree)
        {
            if($tree->depth == 0)
            array_push($array_tree,$tree->tid);
        }
        $i = 0;

        foreach($trees as $tree)
        {
            foreach($tree->parents as $parent)
            {
                if($parent != 0)
                {
                    $array_tree1[$parent][$i]=$tree->tid;
                    $i++;

                }
                //~ if(array_search($tree->tid,$array_tree))
                //~ array_push($array_tree1,$tree->tid);
            }

        }
?>
<ul>
<?php 
foreach($trees as $tree)
{
    if($tree->depth == 0) {
    echo '<li>'.$tree->name;
    if(count($array_tree1[$tree->tid]))
    echo '<ul>';
            foreach($array_tree1[$tree->tid] as $sub)
            {
                echo '<li>'.$sub.'</li>';
                $query_resources = new EntityFieldQuery();
                $query_resources->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
                        ->entityCondition('bundle', 'resouces')
                        ->propertyCondition('status', NODE_PUBLISHED)
                        ->fieldCondition('field_resource_category', 'tid', '21')
                        ->fieldCondition('field_resources_subcategory');
                $result_resources = $query_resources->execute();
                if (isset($result_resources['node'])) {
                    $news_items_resources = array_keys($result_resources['node']);
                    $news_items_res = entity_load('node', $news_items_resources);
                        //echo '<pre>';print_r($news_items_res); echo '</pre>';     
                } else {
                    echo '<p><strong>No Resources</strong></p>';
                }
                    }
            echo '</ul>';
            echo '</li>';
        }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Term relationships aren't kept in a table that the entity API knows about, so you can't use an EFQ to query them.

[`taxonomy_get_tree()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_get_tree/7) exists for exactly this purpose:

> Create a hierarchical representation of a vocabulary.

e.g.

```
$vocab = taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load('foo_vocab');
$tree = taxonomy_get_tree($vocab->vid);
```

You can optionally provide a `$parent_id` as a 2nd argument, to force the root of the tree to a specific term.

Comment: Thanks for quick replay..i have used above line of code get all parent with child terms but how can i integrate this to with my bundle based  query please suugest.

Comment: Please see above code how can i use **$sub** in entity field condition if i use that correct way then automatically display parent with child terms based on admin side selection currently displaying formate like what given in vocabulary i want to map this to my content type please advice.